# "addEventListener is not a function" problem

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I've seen some people having this problem but I can't find a solution that can fit my code. I'm trying to build a memory game using many `<img>` tags inside a `<div>` one, so that in Javascript I can make an addEventListener that can call the same function for different objects. But when I try to open it on Chrome it says:

```
main2.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: img_deck.addEventListener is not a function
```

Below is my code:

HTML:

```html
<body onload="sortDeck()">
    <div class="deck">
        <tr>
            <th> <img id="0" src="back.jpg"> </th>
            <th> <img id="1" src="back.jpg"> </th>
            <th> <img id="2" src="back.jpg"> </th>
            <th> <img id="3" src="back.jpg"> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> <img id="4" src="back.jpg"> </th>
            <th> <img id="5" src="back.jpg"> </th>
            <th> <img id="6" src="back.jpg"> </th>
            <th> <img id="7" src="back.jpg"> </th>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <th> <img id="8" src="back.jpg"> </th>
            <th> <img id="9" src="back.jpg"> </th>
            <th> <img id="10" src="back.jpg"> </th>
            <th> <img id="11" src="back.jpg"> </th>
        </tr>                 
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```js
var img_deck = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
img_deck.addEventListener("click", clickCard);
```

Answer (score 2):

As the method you are using suggests, `getElementsByTagName` returns more than one element, as an array. You could iterate over this array like so:

```
const divs = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
for (const div of divs) {
    div.addEventListener("click", clickCard);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I may sound like a complete newb but what is happening inside those for parentheses? I have never seen something like that

Comment: @YasminLíbano You want an explanation of the inside of the for loop?

Comment: No, I asking about inside of the parentheses, let me be more specific: what does "const div of divs" do?

Comment: It works the same as having `for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)` and then, inside the loop, `const div = divs[i]`

Comment: ohhh I got it. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById` will return an html element which id is same with param.

Whereas `document.getElementsByTagName` returns the array of html elements which tags are same with the param.

So in your script,

```
var img_deck = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
    img_deck.addEventListener("click" , clickCard);
```

img_deck will have the array of elements which tags are `'DIV'`
So you should make a loop for img_deck and add event listener for every element inside that loop

like this

```
var img_deck = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
img_deck.forEach(function(elem){
    elem.addEventListener("click", clickCard);
})
```